# Prevent SQL injection when querying access logs using Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, sql-injection, amazon-athena

AWS Athena allows you to query Cloudfront access logs that are stored in S3. These access logs include URIs that originate from web clients.

If a bad actor included malicious data in this URI how could one make sure that Athena did not get infiltrated by SQL injected URI string? Does Athena or Cloudfront provide any default protections here?

Comment: Unless you use this url as SQL query there should be no injections here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Only AWS WAF provides [protection against SQL injections](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/classic-web-acl-sql-conditions.html).

Please note that it is not the job of the query engine to prevent SQL injections -- it is the job of whatever generates the SQL before sending it to the database.